# JavaScript understanding certain closure behaviors

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

The out put is 12 12 for the following code.

```
var omg = function(){

        var space = {q:12} ;

        var sq = [];

        sq[0] = function(){
                console.log(space.q);
                space.q = 14;
        };

        sq[1] = function(){
                console.log(space.q);
        };



        return sq;

};

omg()[0]();
omg()[1]();
~
```

Why is the output not 12 14 ?!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each `omg()` call returns a new function. Hence, the `omg()[0]()` call changes the local value of `q` of that particular instance. I think if you did it like this:

```
var a = omg()
a[0](); 
a[1]();
```

you'd get the expected output.

Comment: Nit: It returns a new array, which has elements (properties) that name two new functions (which "close over" the `space` in the lexical scope they are created in)...

Answer (score 3):

Each `omg()` generates a separate closure with a separate `space` object.

To get your expected behavior, you need to call `omg()` *once* and call both functions in it using the same variable:

```
var arr = omg();
arr[0]();
arr[1]();
```

Answer (score 1):

You execute two times the `omg()` so you get two different closures with separate `space` object.